# maven Cobertura reports not working as expected

Tags: mockito, cobertura, powermockito, maven-cobertura-plugin

I am using maven with cobertura plugin for my application. The test class what I have written is for controller and running fine without any issues in eclipse.There  are so many dependencies on other classes.I am using mockito and powermockito both .
When I run

> **mvn clean test**

from command prompt it shows all the test cases that are passed.I have around **9 test cases**, but when I run

> **mvn cobertura:cobertura**

it shows only one test case run 
**Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1**
The error what it is showing is in different class[assume it as **X** class] which I have not modified but I am mocking this **X** class in my test class.

1)

> Does cobertura depends on other classes also apart from main test
>   class for code coverage? If so what I need to do .

2)

> I am not using injectmocks in my test class instead I am using new
>   operator to call the controller class.Since inject mocks was calling real methods I have not used this.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can u try mvn clean site:site

Comment: Nope it didn't worked..